Basis of plotting
I need some help in clearing out basics of plotting in various plotting packages. Specifically matplotlib, seaborn and plotly. Certain fundamental principles are always same across all packages. Can you please refer a book or an online resource that has the basic concepts explained in detail?

There are various books out there that contain a lot of material on how to do visualization with matplotlib, seaborn, and plotly. There is the book "Interactive Data Visualization with Python - Second Edition" and "Data Visualization with Python for Beginners".
I think that also a good way to learn about data visualization and visualization with machine learning would be to get information about plotting from machine learning textbooks; a good choice would be "Machine Learning with Pytorch and Scikit-Learn" by Raschka, Liu, and Mirjalili, or "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python" by Muller and Guido. You would be able to get a lot of info about plotting and ML at once!

Here's what I used in the past:

https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/seaborn-python-tutorial
https://docs.kanaries.net/articles/plotly-vs-matplotlib
https://youtu.be/UZDP9IPMqcs

